# Enum type in java, switch cases

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

I need to write iterate method for the traffic lights. The idea is that Red color is 3 min, then it switches on Green and it is 2 min, then it switches on Yellow and it is 1 min and then it switches again on Red one. Iterate method should iterate the state machine for one minute. I understand, it should be done somehow by switch cases, but I can not guess how.... Help me please.

```
public class TrafficLight
{
    private enum State {RED, YELLOW, GREEN};

    public void iterate()
    {
        switch(state)
        {
            case RED:   
            break;

            case GREEN: 
            break;

            case YELLOW:    
            break;
        }

    }

    public void setTimeForState(State state, int time)
    {

    }
}
```

I'm sorry, the system cut my post, there was also about that setTimeForState method, which
changes the waiting time for a specific color in the traffic light.

Comment: you could use `Timer`, but i'm not sure is switch here is nessesery

Comment: Did your professor tell you to use `switch/case`?

Comment: It's still unclear, what the setTimeForState() method has to do. Does it mean, that you've got a start state, and the total time(whats the time unit?), and the method should process the state changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the variable state in your class:

```
class TrafficLight {
    enum State {
        RED, YELLOW, GREEN
    };

    State state = State.GREEN;

    public void iterate() throws InterruptedException {
        switch (this.state) {
        case RED:
            System.out.println("RED");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            this.state = State.GREEN;
            break;

        case GREEN:
            System.out.println("GREEN");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            this.state = State.YELLOW;
            break;

        case YELLOW:
            System.out.println("YELLOW");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            this.state = State.RED;
            break;
        }

    }
```

And in each case wait some time a put state to the next value.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    final TrafficLight a = new TrafficLight();
    while (true) {
        a.iterate();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank u for the answer, I edited the post. If I use threads, then how could I change waiting time in setTimeForState method?

Answer (score 0):

here is street light simulator and it using timer and switch:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class TrafficLight {

    static Timer timer =new Timer();

    private enum State {
        RED(3l), YELLOW(1l), GREEN(3l);
        Long time;

        State(Long time) {
            this.time = time * 1000  * 60;
        }

    };

    State state= State.RED;
    boolean direction = true;

    private static class ChangeState extends TimerTask {
        public ChangeState(TrafficLight lights) {

            this.lights = lights;
        }


        private final TrafficLight lights;


        @Override
        public void run() {

            switch (lights.state){
            case RED:
                lights.direction = false;
                lights.state = State.YELLOW;
                break;
            case YELLOW:
                if (lights.direction)
                    lights.state = State.RED;
                else
                    lights.state = State.GREEN;
                break;
            case GREEN:
                lights.direction = true;
                lights.state = State.YELLOW;
                break;
        }
        System.out.println(lights.state);
            timer.schedule(new ChangeState(lights),1000);// state.time);
        }
    };

    public void run(){
        System.out.println("state");
        timer.schedule(new ChangeState(this), state.time);
    }




    public static void main(String[] a) {
        (new TrafficLight()).run();
    }

}
```